# Keeping a point in the same relative position as a square as it deforms

Tags: math, plot, geometry

Currently, I am trying to get this idea to work in Desmos, so I can transfer it to be used on a separate project.

I want a point, (v), to be placed somewhere within a (0,0) to (1,1) grid space. Then if the corners of the square are moved, the point should be the same relative to the corners.

So if v is at (0.5,0.5), as the square deforms, the new point will be in the center of the new corners at all times.
If v is at (1,0), then the new point should always be wherever that point of the square is moved to, and is unaffected by the other points.

I have a Desmos project that is almost how I want it to work, but testing v at (1,0) doesn't work as expected.

My method had to do with Lerping the new point from 0-p by its coordinates, but that doesn't prevent other points from acting on it when it is at the bounds. So I tried using the distance to the other points to multiply a weight to each point but that wasn't successful either, which I believe is the correct path if done correctly.

https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ynbi2rphce

To explain the variables in my Desmos project:

p1, p2, p3, and p4 are the corners of the square that you can move around to create skews of the square

v is where the starting point is (This should always be between 0 and 1, but if it works beyond those bounds, that's fine as well)

The equation represents where v should be mapped relative to p1, p2, p3, and p4.

I did find this post which I believe is asking a similar question, but I think they are looking for something slightly more involved than I need. I am trying to understand it and work it into my solution, but I have been unsuccessful so far

Answer (score 0):

After really yelling at chatGPT, I was able to get this desmos graph which does exactly what I want!
https://www.desmos.com/calculator/hzzeuhxlia

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).